# Does docker storage driver matter for applications that don't write a lot?

Tags: docker

Assuming that my application doesn't write a lot, do I really have to care about docker storage driver e.g. AUFS, Btrfs, DeviceMapper, etc.? I'm thinking about using the default one that comes with the installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage drivers are also used for storing the *images* that you download, and build, and influences, for example, the time it takes to delete an image, the amount of resources used when deleting images, or the time it takes to start a container from an image.

> I'm thinking about using the default one that comes with the installation.

The 'default' one can vary between the distro you're running on (Debian, Ubuntu, CentOS), the version of the distro, and the kernel version. Docker picks the first available driver on your system, using this order: [driver_linux.go#L51-L58](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/65d79e3e5e537039b244afd7eda29e721a93d84f/daemon/graphdriver/driver_linux.go#L51-L58). However, depending on your use-case, selecting a different driver may have benefits. For example, Docker prioritizes "devicemapper" over "overlay", even though "overlay" is a *lot* faster than devicemapper, but still has some issues that affects *some* users ([see the issue tracker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aarea%2Fstorage%2Foverlay).

For more in-depth information about the available drivers, and information to decide which driver best suits *your* use case, see this section of the documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Your points are valid. However, in my case, let's say I only need my application running, and don't do download, build, delete images frequently, then I might not see a difference in choosing another storage driver. In other words, storage driver may not affect the performance of an application with infrequent writing operations.

Comment: It will have minimum effect, true. Picking a different storage driver is fairly easy though, so why not pick the best available?

Comment: Well, out of the options available: AUFS (gonna be outdated), Btrfs & OverlayFS & ZFS (not ready for production), DeviceMapper (with direct LVM) is the only thing left. But it requires external volume and some configurations. I don't want to complicate things with minimum effect.

Comment: All options should be ready for production, aufs and overlay are actually used extensively in production (most issues we see are with devicemapper, although admittedly many of those related to loop-lvm)